Repeatability for more than 2 measures
I´m trying to calculate repeatability for 4 measures. I see that one of the measures to do this is coefficient of repeatability (CR). The problem is that CR is used in test-retest experiments, for 2 measures, and its formula is CR = Standard deviation within subject x 1.96 x √2.
Would it make sense to adapt this formula to achieve this? Or could I use it like this?
Maybe there is another index to calculate this?
